# Volcano hot end adapter orientation?

Tags: nozzle, e3d-v6, e3d-volcano

Now that V6 nozzles are getting more advanced, as in Nickel coated brass/copper nozzles (e.g. Bondtech CHT® nozzles) the availability for Volcano hot ends seem to lag behind...

A Volcano heat break adapter/nozzle extender has been spotted on the online market places to be used together with the shorter E3D V6 nozzles.

[image: Volcano adapter]

There seems to be confusion about the mounting of the adapter.

Either from the top of the heater block:

[image: Volcano adapter top mounting]

or, from the bottom:

[image: Volcano adapter bottom mounting]

What is the correct positioning of the adapter considering a hex key insert is in the path of the filament, e.g. effects on retraction performance?

[image: Volcano adapter views]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the *intended* mounting is, but I would put the hex socket downward towards the nozzle. Especially with a CHT, the opening to the nozzle (3 openings rather) is significantly wider than the normal filament path (usually actually 1.85-2.00 mm), and having the adapter widen just before it should help the filament reach the entire opening smoothly once it's molten and expanded in the space.

Conversely, mounting it with the hex socket pointed upwards creates a point in the melt zone where the path widens then narrows again. Due to the way viscous fluids work, material that gets into this space is very unlikely to merge back with the main flow; it's going to stay there and **bake**. This could lead to jams or at least increased friction from the molten filament having to pass by carbonized gunk. Even if not, it could leave mismatched color/material filament inside the hotend after a purge, only to have it randomly come out later and ruin your print (or at least make it look ugly).